# What is the role of oil in baked cheesecake with raisins

Tags: baking

I have mislaid my recipe for a baked cheesecake With raisins. When I search for other recipes, all of them add vegetable oil. I can’t remember ever adding oil to the quark mixture.

Is it necessary to add oil? What is the role of adding oil to the filling in this type of cheesecake?

Comment: Hi Inge, welcome to our site! I edited your question somewhat. This is because I think a few people were misled what it is about, and voted to close it (we are restrictive about the type of question we have, and we don't take recipe requests). I hope my edit preserves your original meaning, if not, you can re-edit yourself. Also, if this is a German-style cheesecake made with quark, this information would be relevant to the question, because American-style cheesecakes (with cream cheese) are different in texture and could theoretically have a different interaction with the oil.

Comment: I had a (Dr. Oetker I think) cake mixture for cheesecake that called for (melted) butter in the quark filling but had a note saying "to get a lighter cake just leave out the butter". So I am guessing it is to add taste and "richness" but is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Well said & will try it without the melted butter